# VisualStudioCode-Angular-NPM

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, npm

I tried to install this but it always gives me a Error message, do you know how to fix it?.

```
david@Davids-MacBook-Pro ~ % npm install -g @angular/cli
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.
```

Comment: can you try as admin?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with.

sudo npm install -g @angular/cli